# Can not compile my code

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors

I want to print this sign `/\` but on the compiler, i think everything is fine but can not compile. error appeared as

```
leets.java:13: error: unclosed string literal
System.out.printf ("%s /\",ch);
                     ^
 leets.java:13: error: ';' expected
 System.out.printf ("%s /\",ch);
                     ^
 2 errors
```

My code is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class switchDemo2
{
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
    Scanner i = new Scanner ( System.in );
    System.out.print ( "Enter a character to test: " );
    char ch;
    ch = i.next().charAt(0);
    switch ( ch )
    {
    case 'A': case 'a':
    System.out.printf ("%s /\",ch);
                       break;
    case 'B': case 'b':
        System.out.printf ("%s 13",ch);
    break;
    case 'C': case 'c':
    System.out.printf ("%s )",ch);
    break;
    case 'D': case 'd':
    System.out.printf ("%s 1)",ch);
    break;
    case 'E': case 'e':
    System.out.printf ("%s 3",ch);
    break;
    case 'F': case 'f':
    System.out.printf ("%s 1=",ch);
    break;
    default:
    System.out.printf ("%s not a lowercase vowel\n",ch);
}
}
```

Comment: you need to read about literal string escape sequence in java

Comment: as others have told you, it is a escape sequence that is missing and  It is not a good practice to name the class beginning with smaller case. rename it to SwitchDemo2 :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape backslashes as .

```
 System.out.printf ("%c /\\",ch);
```

You can see more information about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Few comments :

1. You used `"%s"` for characters, you can use `"%c` for characters. See formatting [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).
2. You did not close the scanner, you will get so warning. You should close it using `Scanner.close()` method.
3. Last curly brace `}` is remaining.

Comment: +1 just because of being fast (you see, they all say the same, there is no point in me doing it too... so I'll just upvote you).

Comment: +1. And you should use `System.out.printf ("%c /\\",ch);` since ch is char (not String).

Comment: Thanks, So helpful. I am trying to write an alphabet of leets. My program will convert letters to leet. Should I write all letters as a case or is there any other way?

Comment: @Theraot : Exactly and totally agreed, I would answer if I have any new point explaining answer instead of giving same answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf ("%s /\\",ch);
```

Instead of `System.out.printf ("%s /\",ch);`

```
 Escape Sequence    Description
 \t     Insert a tab in the text at this point.
 \b     Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
 \n     Insert a newline in the text at this point.
 \r     Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
 \f     Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
 \'     Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
 \"     Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
 \\     Insert a backslash character in the text at this point
```

[Here  is the Tutorial on characters in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes needs to be escaped: -

```
System.out.printf ("%c /\\",ch);
```

And you can change your: - `switch ( ch )` to `switch(Character.toLowerCase(ch))`, to avoid having cases for both `A` and `a`. Just use `case 'a':`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you;

System.out.printf ("%s '/\\'",ch);

Regards,

Dinuka